# Solving a system of linear equations over the natural numbers in polynomial time

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

In the following, a natural number is defined as a nonnegative integer.

Given a matrix $A$ consisting of only natural numbers, and a vector $\vec b$ of natural numbers, how do you find the set of solutions $\vec x$ of the equation $A \vec x = \vec b$ where all the components of $\vec x$ are natural numbers?

The approach described on Wikipedia for solving [systems of Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations) does not ensure that the solutions are nonnegative. Adding that constraint makes it a special case of integer linear programming, which is NP-Hard in general. Is there a polynomial time algorithm?

Comment: Couldn't you just use Gaussian elimination for this? Because a linear system has at most one solution, and if that number is not an integer then it has no integer solutions? I am almost certainly wrong however.

Comment: @Colonizor48 It's over the natural numbers (that is, $n \geq 0$) not the integers. Also, the equation may not have a unique solution depending on the rank of $A$.

Comment: oh yeah, if the determinant is zero then I could see why the problem would be NP hard then. But I presume it should be easy on almost all instances, as almost all systems will have nonzero determinant and therefore one unique solution or no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this is a special case of the Knapsack Problem. It is NP-complete, so that there is no polynomial-time algorithm.

Reference: [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19758/linear-diophantine-equation-in-non-negative-integers).

Comment: It's a generalization of unlimited subset sum. One equation on its own is equivalent to USS, which is NP Hard. Thank you.